# Links to third party projects in documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, spam, advertising

I created **remark** in [this documentation topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/740/xml-documentation-comments#t=201607221327141499303):

> Some times you need to **create extended text documentation** from you
>   xml comments. Unfortunatly ***there are no standard way for it***. But
>   there are some separate projects that you can use dot this case:
>
> - [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/)
> - [Docu](http://docu.jagregory.com/)
> - [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/)

I think this info can be valuable for users that interrested in topic, but it has links to third party projects.

Is it ok to add this kind of links in documentation?

I mean it could lead to "advertising corner" in documentation that as I see right now could be not really good.